# Why would a (working) theme function defined in nodequeue module not be registered in theme registry?

Tags: hooks, theming

Trying to overide a  theme function defined in nodequeue  from another custom module:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function nodequeue_theme() {
  return array(
       'nodequeue_arrange_subqueue_form_table' => array(
      'render element' => 'form',
    ),
  );
}


/**
 * Theme the subqueue overview as a sortable list.
 *
 * @ingroup themeable
 */
function theme_nodequeue_arrange_subqueue_form_table($variables) {
  $form = $variables['form'];
  // Build output snipped for clarity...
  $output = 'bunch of code';

 return $output;
}
```

I was expecting to use `theme_registry_alter` but upon doing a var_dump of `$theme_registry` in the alter hook (after cache was flushed), it seems the function is not registered. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
function yourtheme_nodequeue_arrange_subqueue_form_table($variables) {}
```

I don't think you can override module functions from the theme layer without theme_hook_function or hook_function_alter... You'll need to create a module to override nodequeue_theme() - take at look at [drupal_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/drupal_alter/7)

Comment: Yes, I had resigned myself to doing this but initially wanted to overide the theme function from the theme itself.